# establish bluetooth connection between two devices in j2me application

Tags: java-me, bluetooth

I need to establish a bluetooth connection between two devices so that the data can be send/received continuously. I am new to j2me and under the 'learning and implementing' phase.
   So if anyone can suggest me an easiest way to get how to establish bluetooth between two mobile devices.
   It can be a tutorial or a blog or any kind of reference site.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bluetooth API demo application in the J2ME SDK. I would advise reading the source code it contains first.